# Alarm not working in KitKat

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have this in my activity :

```
        AlarmManager alarmMgr;
        PendingIntent alarmIntent;

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 20);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmBroadcastReceiver.class);
        alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                this.getApplicationContext(), 123456, intent, 0);

        alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
                alarmIntent);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

And this is my broadcast receiver class :

```
    @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Intent mIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmMessageActivity.class); 
    mIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(mIntent);

    Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) context
            .getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    vibrator.vibrate(2000);     
}
```

I have also added these to the manifest file

```
    <activity
        android:name=".AlarmMessageActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_alarm_message" >
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".AlarmBroadcastReceiver" >
    </receiver>
```

The AlarmMessageActivity class is just a simple page to display a text.

The above code works for sdk 8. But for Kitkat it does not work and i am also not getting any errors while setting the alarm  or when the broadcast receiver is executed. I want to have the alarm working for all versions, my min sdk is 8.

Can anybody tell me where i am possibly wrong. I am new to android.

Comment: Check : https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4.html#Behaviors

Comment: @jenuine - Have updated the question with manifest code.

Comment: The AlarmManager works even in KitKat. But it works **weird**. `When you set your app's targetSdkVersion to "19" or higher, alarms that you create using either set() or setRepeating() will be inexact.`
 and `This inexact batching behavior applies only to updated apps. If you've set the targetSdkVersion to "18" or lower, your alarms will continue behave as they have on previous versions when running on Android 4.4.` This is why I prefer targeting API Level **18**.